# Getting Error in SwaggerUI in Magento V.2.2

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.2, swaggerui

The `SwaggerUI` has been working perfectly fine but now after installing some Modules, I think the Swagger is not at all working.

It's custom module and custom admin theme.

I checked the logs and `found the error` to be this:

```
The service interface name "["Magento\\Store\\Api\\StoreRepositoryInterface","Magento","Store","StoreRepository","Interface"]" is invalid.
```

I have already tried restarting the server and disabled caching as well but still no luck.

**Any suggestions?**

Thankss!